# Attach UILabel to image thumbnail bottom (varying heights)

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have a view with image view and Label. Image view displays images of varying sizes and it is  fixed to the top(see image) I want to dynamically glue text label to the bottom of every image without any space between image thumbnail and UILabel.

[image]

Comment: I presume you use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` on the image?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that programically. I assume that you have UILabel attached to "label" and the image to "imageView" variables.

```
CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;

labelFrame.origin.y = imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height + any_space_you_want_between_image_and_label;

label.frame = labelFrame;
```

That will change the position of label just bellow the imageView. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks BlackByte. Yours and Andrei's solutions match so it has to be true. :)

Comment: Actually they don't match (no offense @BlackByte). 
By just using the frame.height you always get the same value.

Comment: @Andrei, frame.height is error. It must be frame.size.height. Sorry. And the other is frame.origin.y.

Comment: @BlackByte Right. But even with `frame.size.height` you always get the size of the frame - to actually remove the "trailing" space between the image and the label you need to get the actual height of the image inside the UIImageView.

Comment: @AndreiStoleru Yes I understand your point. However it depends how he has written his code. If he create dynamically UIImageView with UImage, than it will be different every time.

Answer (score 1):

Because as you mentioned you use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` for the content mode the solution is a bit harder.
You have to actually calculate the final height of the image (the actual size of the image inside the UIImageView):

```
    //UIImage *img = ...; UIImageView *imgView = ....
    CGFloat imageWidth = img.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = img.size.height;
    CGFloat viewWidth = imgView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat viewHeight = imgView.frame.size.height;
    float actualHeight = imageHeight * viewWidth / imageWidth;
// this is the actual height of the UIImage inside the UIImageView
    CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
    labelFrame.origin.y = imageView.frame.origin.y + actualHeight + any_space_you_want_between_image_and_label;
    label.frame = labelFrame;
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei. I still have to implement this so will mark this as correct answer once i verify it. This surely looks like the right way.